# Why does slime-vim indent improperly while paredit is on?

Tags: vim, scheme, lisp

When I write `(define (foo bar) <Enter>)` it will indent like this:

[image: picture 1].

But I think normally it should have indent like this:

[image: picture 2].

I don't know how to fix it, my platform is Mac OS X, the vim version is 7.4.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `(define (foor bar))` alone is an invalid syntax, the correct syntaxes being either:

```
(define id expr)
```

or:

```
(define (head args) body ... +)
```

(see for instance the [syntax of Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html), or [this syntax of Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/tspl2d/grammar.html)).

So, when you write `(define (foo bar))` the editor expects the body of the function, and formats your input so that you can start typing it:

```
(define (foo bar)
..|
  )
```

Comment: That seems incorrect to me. It should still format it like in the second picture (and that's how it does in Emacs), since you don't want to have the closing paren on its own line. With that formatting you would have to manually remove the linebreak and spaces once you write the body

Comment: I don't think that in this case the words “correct” or “incorrect” are appropriate. We are discussing the behaviour of an editor, specialized for a certain language, that has to make certain decisions based on user input. For instance, in Emacs, if you write RETURN then ')' after `(define (foo bar)`, the parenthesis in indented. Sometimes grammar-aware editors get in the way of our habits of writing code (especially if using a wrong syntax). If you dont like the default behaviour of vim + slime, you are free to change it, either by configuring or modifying the plugin, or to use another editor.

Comment: I used the word "incorrect", because it seems to be objectively wrong for how Lisp code is generally formatted. You don't leave a closing paren on its own line, so if the editor puts it there, it will cause unnecessary work for the programmer. The indentation in Emacs on the other hand is correct, because you're always supposed to indent the body (I haven't encountered a situation where Emacs would indent it wrongly).